# Isn't $P(X>x_{0.9})=P(Z>1.28)=0.1?$

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I have the following exercise in my textbook:

Assume that the distribution of the body mass index (BMI) among all the citizens of a country is normal with mean and standard deviation equal to 25 and 2 respectively. An individual is considered to have a “normal weight” if his or her BMI belongs to the interval centered on the mean and with width equal to four population standard deviations. On the basis of the previous information, answer the following requests.

Compute the value of BMI exceeded exactly by 10% of the heaviest citizens.

The answer in the textbook is the following:

$P(X>x_{0.9})=P(Z>(X_{0.9}-25)/2)=0.9\rightarrow (x_{0.9}-25)/2\rightarrow x_{0.9}=27.56$

I'm confused, isn't $P(X>x_{0.9})=P(Z>1.28)=0.1?$

[image]

Comment: $P(X>x_{0.9})=P(Z>1.282)=0.1$ is equivalent to $P(X\le x_{0.9})=P(Z\le 1.282)=0.9$

Comment: @Henry The reason why the OP was confused is because the equation that the textbook wrote is **not** what you wrote.  That is why my answer was accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion is warranted:  the solution clearly contains an error.  Either the intent was
$$\Pr[X \le x_{0.9}] = \Pr[Z \le (x_{0.9} - 25)/2] = 0.9,$$ or $$\Pr[X > x_{0.9}] = \Pr[Z > (x_{0.9} - 25)/2] = 0.1.$$

That is to say, the probability that $X$ is below the $90^{\rm th}$ percentile $x_{0.9}$ is $0.9$, or the probability that $X$ exceeds the $90^{\rm th}$ percentile is $0.1$.

If you solve for $x_{0.9}$ according to what the text wrote, you would get
$$\Pr[Z > (x_{0.9} - 25)/2] = 0.9$$ implies $$\frac{x_{0.9} - 25}{2} = -1.28155,$$ hence $$x_{0.9} \approx 22.4369.$$  You would get the $10^{\rm th}$ percentile, not the $90^{\rm th}$.

Comment: sorry but isn't the exercise  requesting the BMI of the  heaviest 10%?

Comment: @tommik The equation that we are told was provided by the textbook says $$\Pr[X > x_{0.9}] = \color{red}{0.9}.$$  This is incorrect, as I have clearly explained in my answer, and shown **why** it is incorrect by calculating the resulting quantile.

Comment: I agree with you that the given equation is wrong but reading the text I interpret it as $P[X>x_{0.9}]=0.1$ with quantile 1.28. Am I wrong?. Usually $x_{0.9}$ indicate 90% percentile of the distribution...

Comment: @tommik I don't understand why you are not reading the question:  It **clearly** says:  "The answer in the textbook is the following:" $$P(X>x_{0.9})=P(Z>(X_{0.9}-25)/2)=\color{red}{0.9}\rightarrow (x_{0.9}-25)/2\rightarrow x_{0.9}=27.56$$ where I have highlighted the error in red.  And I am pointing out that either the inequality is reversed or the value of $0.9$ in red text should instead be $0.1$.  And I have stated this **CLEARLY** multiple times.

Comment: @tommik It seems like the OP is the only other person who actually recognized the error in the text.

Answer (score 2):

$$P(X>x_{0.9})=P(Z>1.28)=10\%$$

is exactly what your textbook is requiring:

> the value of BMI exceeded exactly by 10% of the heaviest citizens.

once you get the quantile $=1.28$ you standardize back obtaining the BMI value

$$1.28\times 2+25=27.56$$